# How to modify the xpath from my code to retrieve data needed

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

So I have a scrapy that retrieves the data from  tag and then writes it in a csv. I now need to modify the xpath so it can read a var like the one below. From "var digitalData" I'll need the data from "product". I'll post my code too below.

```
var digitalData = {
        "page" : {
            "pageInfo" : {
                "siteCode" : siteCode,
                "siteSection": "", 
                "pageName" : "", 
                "pageURL" : pageURL,
                "pageTrack" : "" 
                },
            "pathIndicator" : { 
                "depth_2" : "mobile",
                "depth_3" : "mobile",
                "depth_4" : "smartphones",
                "depth_5" : "galaxy-s9"
                }
        },
        "user" : {
            "loginStatus" : ""
            },
        "product" : {
            "category" : "", 
            "model_code" : "SM-G960FZPDBTU",
            "model_name" : "SM-G960F/DS",
            "displayName" : "Galaxy S9 Hybrid Sim 64GB",
            "pvi_type_code" : "", 
            "pvi_type_name" : "Mobile", 
            "pvi_subtype_code" : "", 
            "pvi_subtype_name" : "Smartphone"
            }
};
```

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json
import csv
import re

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes1"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('so_52069753.csv','r') as csvf:
            urlreader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
            for url in urlreader:
                if url[0]=="y":
                    yield scrapy.Request(url[1])
        with open('so_52069753_out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Category', 'Type', 'Model', 'SK']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()

    def parse(self, response):

        regex = re.compile(r'"product"\s*:\s*(.+?\})', re.DOTALL)
        source_json = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'var digitalData')]/text()").re_first(regex)

        if source_json:
            source_json = re.sub(r'//[^\n]+', "", source_json)
            product = json.loads(source_json)
            product_category = product["pvi_type_name"]
            product_type = product["pvi_subtype_name"]
            product_model = product["displayName"]
            product_name = product["model_name"]

        if source_json:
            source = source_json[0]
            #yield ({'Category': get_values("pvi_subtype_name", source), 'Type': get_values("pathIndicator.depth_5", source), 'SK': get_values("model_name", source)})
            with open('so_52069753_out.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                fieldnames = ['Category', 'Type', 'Model', 'SK']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writerow({'Category': product_category, 'Type': product_type, 'Model': product_model, 'SK': product_name})
```

How can I modify my xpath to read the "var DigitalData"? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try using js2xml: https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml to parse the JS code for you.

Comment: It's a long one, but [This pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cvC4V0/1) should work. Regardless of length it's still pretty efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't process (using `json.loads()`) whole `digitalData` vaariable because of

> "siteCode" : siteCode,

and

> "pageURL" : pageURL,

so I try to get only product section:

```
def parse(self, response):

    regex = re.compile(r'"product"\s*:\s*(.+?\})', re.DOTALL)        
    source_json = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'var digitalData')]/text()").re_first(regex)

    if source_json:

        # Now we need to remove comments from the JSON:
        # "category" : "", // pathIndicator depth정보 이용하여 설정

        # source_json = re.sub(r'//.+$', "", source_json, re.MULTILINE) # this regex doesn't work for me
        source_json = re.sub(r'//[^\n]+', "", source_json)

        product = json.loads(source_json)

        product_category = product["category"]
```

Comment: Hello @gangabass! Thank for your answer!  I have an error for the code which sounds like this:    source_json = re.sub(ur'//[^\n]+', "", source_json)
                                                                              
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.   The error is after the "+" sign. I will update the code in my question above too.

Comment: I fixed the error @gangabass. I've eliminated the 'u' from the: source_json = re.sub(ur'//[^\n]+', "", source_json). So now it looks like: source_json = re.sub(r'//[^\n]+', "", source_json). The problem is that in the final csv where I store the information it return the right headers but the information is ",,," so it didn't retrieves nothing. I will update the code in my question, so you can see  how it looks now. I don't have errors, but it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @user7362809 please give one url from your input file

Comment: @user7362809 your code works for me (for this url: https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-s9/)

Comment: and it writes the data in the final csv?

Comment: I've solved it, too! Thank you a lot @gangabass! Have a nice day! спасибо!

Comment: @user7362809 What was a problem? Don't forget to accept my answer :-)

Comment: I was a silly mistake from my side. I didn't add the right url in the input csv. Thank you again! I've marked it as correct :)